# CSS Transition on Images Causing Hard Edges

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I've been experimenting with CSS transitions lately, and I keep running into an issue when making shrinking headers.

In my example, the script C and The Corbo Group are both transparent PNGs. I'm adding a shrink class through jQuery and using CSS transitions to handle the animation.

When the transition completes, there is around 1 second of pixelation before the browser anti-aliasing completes. Is there any way to prevent this?

I've tried using `transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);`

But that seems to cause the image to *stay* in the pixelated state.

Here's an example of my css

```
header img.corbo-c {max-width:118px; margin:20px 0 0 -38px; transition:all 0.25s ease;}

header.shrink img.corbo-c {max-width:60px; margin:10px 0 0 -20px; transition:all 0.25s ease;}
```

Pen Demonstrating Issue:

http://codepen.io/roachdesign/pen/BoOGYy

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please, provide jsfiddle.

Comment: @alirezasafian Added codepen

Comment: I tried in Chrome Version 46.0.2490.80 m and Firefox 41.0.2. In Firefox, it worked correctly but in Chrome the image was pixelated. I think, it is Chrome rendering bug.